# How do I make it so that pages that don't physically exist link to certain page only if after a certain directory?

Tags: php, apache2, uri

How do I make it so that when a user goes to `mydomain.com/test/<any page after this point>` It displays the page at `mydomain.com/testhandler/` and without returning any error. For an example I have a system in place where I use the URI to link to an xml File with the information for the page and I need every part after `/test` to link to it

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config (whether that be the main apache config or vhosts block) Add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/test/*" "/testhandler/" [PT]
```

respectively. See:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html